# Add filter row to dynamically created knockout.js grid

Tags: knockout.js

I have view model which i am using to bind to a table of results. The view dynamically renders the table of results without any prior knowledge of number or name of columns, which is great. Similar to that described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446548/set-table-columns-dynamically-from-ko-observablearray/17447273?noredirect=1#comment31616566_17447273) and in the interest of keeping generic and not domain specific i have adapted the code sample from that questions answer here.

However i need to add a filter row to allow the user to filter, i have added a row of inputs based on the column names in the code below and attempted to bind them to the view model. It is important that they are bound to the view model so that when i refresh the grid the view model knows about any filters applied.

I have tried a couple of things

- firstly as shown in code snippet below i have created an observable filter object and attempted to bind each field in the table to a property on that filter object. This however does not seem to work.
- another option i tried was to create an observable array of filter objects based on the column names and bind the filter columns to that which also didnt seem to work

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Many thanks, Ed

JS

```
var VM = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray();
  self.filters = ko.observable({});

  self.columnNames = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.items().length === 0)
        return [];
    var props = [];
    var obj = self.items()[0];
    for (var name in obj)
        props.push(name);
    return props;


  });

};
var vm = new VM();

ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.items.push({
  'Name': 'John',
  'Age': 25
});
vm.items.push({
'Name': 'Morgan',
'Age': 26
});
```

View :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: columnNames">
        <th> <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>

        </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >

   <!-- add filter rows -->
    <tr data-bind="foreach: $root.columnNames">
        <td ><input type='text' data-bind="value: $root.filters[$data]"/></td>
    </tr>
   <!-- add the items -->
   <!-- ko foreach: items -->
   <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columnNames">
        <td data-bind="text: $parent[$data]"></td>
    </tr>
   <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a fiddle in which `filters` are stored into an object `{Col1 : Value1, Col2 : Value2...}`.

Now the `columnNames` computed returns an object that contains both the header of the column and its filter.

I also created a filteredItems computed that contains only items which matched the filters.

The `subscriptions` array aims to keep a track of subscriptions in order to delete them when the number of column changes.

```
 var VM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.filters = ko.observable({});
    self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
        var filters = self.filters();

        var items = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function (item) {
            for (var col in filters) {
                var v = (item[col] || '').toString(); // cell value
                var f = filters[col]; // what you typed in header
                if (v.indexOf(f) < 0) return false; // filter is contains
            }
            return true;
        });
        return items;
    });
    var subscriptions = [];
    self.columnNames = ko.computed(function () {
        // clean old subscriptions
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(subscriptions, function (s) { s.dispose(); });
        subscriptions = [];
        if (self.items().length === 0) return [];
        var props = [];
        var obj = self.items()[0];
        for (var name in obj) {         
            var p = { name: name, filter: ko.observable('') };
            // subscribe : so when you type something, filterOnChanged will be invoked.
            subscriptions.push(p.filter.subscribe(filterOnChanged, p));
            props.push(p);
        }
        return props;
    });

    var filterOnChanged = function (value) {
        console.log([this.name, value]);
        var filters = self.filters();
        filters[this.name] = value;
        self.filters(filters);
    };

};
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xpx7f/20/)

Comment: Hi Damien, thanks for such a quick response. I like the solution and it works great, however is very slow when dealing with a large number of rows, i'm guessing because each time a row is added all subscriptions are disposed and recreated, also my filters are passed to the server rather than filtering a local list. I have modified so that columnNames is computer from a new observable firstRow which is only populated when the initial data is loaded and not updated when the data is filtered.